# Deploy the Web App to Heroku for Salesforce-Canvas Framework

Tags: git, canvas, heroku, salesforce

In this walkthrough, you previously ran the “hello world” Web app locally before adding it as a canvas app and testing it. Now
that your canvas app works locally, you’re ready to deploy your “hello world” Web app to Heroku and run it from there. Here’s
how you do it.

If you haven’t already, log into Heroku and install Heroku Toolbelt following the links in the Prerequisites.

1. Open a command window, navigate to c:\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK, and enter the following command:
   git init. This re-initializes the directory as a Git repository.
2. In the command window, enter the following command: heroku create. This creates a new “shell” app on Heroku.
   Confirmation that the app was created looks like this:
   Creating deep-samurai-7923... done, stack is cedar
   http://deep-samurai-7923.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:deep-samurai-7923.git
   Git remote heroku added
3. To rename this Heroku app, enter the following command in the command window: heroku rename newAppName -—app oldAppName.
   In this example, oldAppName is deep-samurai-7923. The newAppName you create must begin with a letter and can only
   contain lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes. You’ll see a confirmation of the renaming that looks similar to this:
   http://newappName.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:newappName.git
   The newappName must be unique across all Heroku apps. This name becomes part of the URL for your app, for example, newappName.herokuapp.com.
4. Run the following command in the command window: git add -A. This adds the entire SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK project to the Git repository. If you’re working in the Windows environment, you might see some messages about LF (line feeds) being replaced by CRLF (carriage return line feeds).
5. Enter the following command in the command window to commit the changes along with a comment: git commit —m “MyChangeComments”.
6. Enter the following command in the command window to deploy the changes to Heroku: git push heroku master

**when i am trying this Procedure for Canvas(Saleforce) SDK Framework I get below Error:
Permission Denied
fatal:could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have correct access rights and the repository exists.
I am a Salesforce developer and new to git and heroku please HELP**